# How to Get Environment Value in Config File

Tags: laravel, phpdotenv

Currently, I have an environment variable in my .env file.

```
MY_NAME_TEST=Testing
```

How do I pass that variable as part of a path in a config file? I'm trying to get a path similar to below:

```
base_path('Plugins/Testing/Database/Migrations/')
```

Notice the "Testing" part of the path in the sample above; I need that name to be different each time.

Comment: Would this work? `base_path('Plugins/'.env('MY_NAME_TEST', 'Testing').'/Database/Migrations/')`

Comment: @ljubadr your comment will also *set* the env variable, something that should be noted.

Comment: That's true, I just thought that it would be better to have fallback if `MY_NAME_TEST` is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're able to retreive the values anywhere in your laravel project by making use of the `env` function.

```
env('MY_NAME_TEST'); // returns "Testing"
```

In your case it would be used like so:

```
base_path('Plugins/' . env('MY_NAME_TEST') . '/Database/Migrations/'
```

The second parameter the `env` function takes is a default value if a value is not already set.